# ZipArchive::extractTo doesn't working on Windows Platform

Tags: php-ziparchive

I'm using the following code **(Windows Hosting - Plesk/Win)** :

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('file.zip');
if ($res === TRUE) {
$path = getcwd(); 
$path = str_replace("/","\\",$path);
echo $path;
$zip->extractTo('E:\\Vhosts\\domain.com\\httpdocs\\test\\');

  $zip->close();
  echo 'Ok!';
} else {
  echo 'Error!';
}
?>
```

When I run this code, the following message appears:

> Warning:
>   ZipArchive::extractTo(E:\Vhosts\domain.com\httpdocs\test/image1.jpg)
>   [ziparchive.extractto]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   E:\Vhosts\domain.com\httpdocs\test\extractphp.php on line 10

I don't now why this command put a slash before the unzipped file (test/image1.jpg).

How can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: Some tools are platform-agnostic, and work with either "\" or "/" path separators - even on Windows. Can you try without replacing them?

Comment: In this example, the variable $path makes no difference. I've specified the exact path on extractTo. However I did test without str_replace. Didn't work.

Comment: Without str_replace I get this message: Warning: ZipArchive::extractTo(E:\Vhosts\domain.com\httpdocs\test/extractphp.php) [ziparchive.extractto]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in E:\Vhosts\domain.com\httpdocs\test\extractphp.php on line 8. Pay attention on "wrong" slash before the file.

Comment: Can you try one more thing: using forward slashes all the way? (That is, assuming it's not *literally* an access-denied error, by the way. Can you check that as well?)

Comment: I tried and got this: Warning: ZipArchive::extractTo(E:/Vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/test/image1.jpg) [ziparchive.extractto]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in E:\Vhosts\domain.com\httpdocs\test\extractphp.php on line 6

Comment: I modified the user permissions in Plesk Panel and the code works very well